# Time complexity of the given function with constant loop and recursion

Tags: java, algorithm, time-complexity, big-o

What would be the time complexity for this, will it be O(​​​​logn)?

```
fun(int n) {
    if (n < 2)
        return 1;
    int counter = 0;
    for (int i = 1; i <= 8; i++)
        fun(n / 2);
    for (int i = 1; i <= Math.pow(n, 3); i++)
        counter++;
}
```

Comment: Why would it be log n? You've got a for-loop up to n-cubed in the function.

Comment: What does `fun` return?  `int` or `void`? Anyway it doesn't compile.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The complexity of the function is:

```
T(n) = n^3 + 8*T(n/2)
```

- `n^3` comes from the last loop, which is going from `1` to `n^3`
- `8*T(n/2)` from calling `fun(n/2)` 8 times (in the first loop)

To find the complexity, one can use [master theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Master_theorem_(analysis_of_algorithms)) with: `a = 8, b = 2, f(n) = n^3`

Using case 2:

`log_2(8) = 3`, and indeed `f(n)` is in `Theta(n^3)`, giving this function complexity of `O(n^3*logn)`.

Comment: The variable `counter` is not used, so optimizer may remove the last loop.